# Access user object in decorator from request object for a logged in user

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my DRF app driven with APIView(), I want to add a single decorator. The decorator is:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from payment.models import Purchase

def client_has_paid(function):
    '''
    Has the client paid or have active subscription fee?
    '''

    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):

        iccd = request.user.user_profile.iccd
        filters = {'iccd': iccd , 'active': 1 } 

        try:
            purchase = Purchase.objects.get(**filters)
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            raise PermissionDenied

    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

The error is in line **request.user.user_profile.iccd** which states user_profile don't exist (it does exist). doing

```
     print(request.user)
```

gives out AnnonymousUser

Without the decorator, the API does print the correct user information as long as the passed token is valid.

The API that uses it is:

```
@method_decorator(client_has_paid, name='dispatch')
class AddIngredient(APIView):
    permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope]

    def post(self, request, cropped_land_id, format=None):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create drf style permission class and use it in your decorator, which would be more convenient. Just try this:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions


class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        iccd = request.user.user_profile.iccd
        filters = {'iccd': iccd , 'active': 1 } 

        try:
            purchase = Purchase.objects.get(**filters)
            return True
        except:
            raise False
```

and use it in your view like:

```py
class AddIngredient(APIView):
    permission_classes = [CustomPermission]

    def post(self, request, cropped_land_id, format=None):
```